# Sequelize - Nested Query Condition to Top Level

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to query a database of promotions that don't have phone number in the blacklist of promotion.
my project use sequelize.org for manage database.

**Mock Database**  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/438587/1

**Association**

- Promotion Model

  - this.belongsToMany(models.CustomerList, {
    through: models.BlacklistPromotion,
    as: 'Blacklist',
    });
  - this.belongsToMany(models.CustomerList, {
    through: models.WhitelistPromotion,
    as: 'Whitelist',
    });
- CustomerList Model

  - this.belongsToMany(models.CustomerPhoneNumber, {through: models.CustomerListPhoneNumber,});
- CustomerPhoneNumber Model

  - this.belongsToMany(models.CustomerList, { through: models.CustomerListPhoneNumber});

**Code sequelize findAndCountAll Promotion**

```
        await Promotion.findAndCountAll({
            where : {},        <-------- i want query here or somewhere.
            include :[
                {
                    model: CustomerList,
                    as: 'Blacklist',
                    include :[{
                        model: CustomerPhoneNumber,
                        as: 'CustomerPhoneNumbers',
                        attributes: ['phone_number'],
                        through: {
                            attributes: [],
                        }
                    }],
                    through: {
                        attributes: [],
                    },
                },
            {
                    model: CustomerList,
                    as: 'Whitelist',
                    include :[{
                        model: CustomerPhoneNumber,
                        as: 'CustomerPhoneNumbers',
                        attributes: ['phone_number'],
                        through: {
                            attributes: [],
                        }
                    }],
                    through: {
                        attributes: [],
                    },
            }
            ]
        })
```

**when run query**

```
        {
        "Promotion": [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Promotion1"
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Promotion2"
            },
            {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Promotion3",
            "Blacklist": [
                {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Group5",
                "CustomerPhoneNumbers": [
                    {
                    "id": 5,
                    "phone_number": "0877777777"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 6,
                    "phone_number": "0888888888"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 7,
                    "phone_number": "0899999999"
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
```

try query

```
 where : { 
          '$Blacklist.CustomerPhoneNumbers.phone_number$': {
             [Op.ne]: '0877777777',
           }
         }
// output
   {
        "Promotion": [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Promotion1"
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Promotion2"
            },
            {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Promotion3",
            "Blacklist": [
                {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Group5",
                "CustomerPhoneNumbers": [
                    {
                    "id": 6,
                    "phone_number": "0888888888"
                    },
                    {
                    "id": 7,
                    "phone_number": "0899999999"
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
        }
```

but i want to remove promotion3

### What do you expect to happen?

> Find solution query a database of promotions that don't have phone number in the blacklist of promotion.

I want to get:

```
{
        "Promotion": [
            {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Promotion1"
            },
            {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Promotion2"
            },
        ]
        }
```